# Extra text below the comments, how do you do this?

Tags: support, questions, answers, post-notice

In [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18750) I see there's an extra paragraph of text after the end of the comments, the bit that starts "We're looking for long answers..."

It's not part of the markdown of the question itself, and it's not a bounty or a system notification like "Migrated from...". So how do you do this?

Also, is this the right place to ask such question, or should I take it to meta.stackoverflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're called 'post notices', and as Jack mentioned, only diamond mods can add (and remove) them from questions to try and guide the answers posted.  I've most frequently used them in place of or in addition to protecting questions, so as to minimize the number of low quality answers from new users.

I threw one up on this meta question so everyone knows exactly what you're referring to.

Comment: OK, that's clear.

Comment: @Keen - out of random curiosity, have you noticed whether such notices are effective? (the reason I asked was that - while I must have previously seen these notes due to reading almost all non-Futurama questions - I for the life of me can't recall ever noticing one until reading this META question)

Answer (score 5):

That is a special text that the moderators add to questions that are generating useless 1 line answers. It is to encourage people to give thorough answers instead.

This is not something a regular user can add to their question.

Comment: Ah, thanks. If you say "moderators", do you mean 10K+ users, or only diamond ones? And is it just on this site? Haven't seen it anywhere else in the SE network.

Comment: Actually, a regular user can add some text in the same area of the question.  They just have to post a bounty to the question.  The text is then given as the reason for the bounty.

Comment: @Iszi But bounties expire, so that text is temporary.  These post notices stay there until a mod removes them.

Comment: @Keen Correct, but it is still a good way to draw more attention to the question - and a way for non-moderators to request particular clarification in a similar manner as shown above.